# Using VB 6.0 to generate pseudorandom numbers with a Gaussian distribution

Tags: random, vb6

I would like to generate some pseudorandom numbers on (-*infinity*, *infinity*) with a Gaussian distribution of standard deviation *s* and mean *m*. Any suggestions about how to do this? I'd appreciate any help in the right direction, as there seems to be a huge literature out there as how best to generate pseudorandom numbers.

Comment: The most common methods are Box-Muller transform, Marsaglia polar method, and the Ziggurat. Google should find lots of data about all of these.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a Gaussian distribution (also known as a normal distribution) buy using a uniform random number generator and an appropriate algorithm. Check out [stackoverflow link to Gaussian algorithms][1]

Do you really want to go from +/- infinity?  Does that make sense?

A simple algorithm to use is the Box-Muller method.

Normal Dist. Random # = SQRT(-2*LN(RAND()))*SIN(2*PI()*RAND())

The Box-Muller method is mathematically exact if implemented with a perfect uniform random number generator and infinite precision. (oops.. in that formula, mu/mean =0 and sigma = 1 and random #'s are between 0 and 1) see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Box-MullerTransformation.html